# Shiro match any filter in the chain

Tags: shiro

im using shiro 1.2.3 in my project and try to solve the following issue.
I have users having a role `admin` who should have access to url `/user/edit.xhtml`.
I have also users having a permission `user:edit:*` who should have access to the same url `/user/edit.xhtml`.

I tried to solve it this way:
`[urls]
/user/edit.xhtml = perms[user:edit:?], roles[admin]`

This does not work, as users having the role `admin`, do not have the permission `user:edit` explicitly.
The chain will fail after the first filter.

Second approach was:
`[urls]
/user/edit.xhtml = perms[user:edit:?]
/user/edit.xhtml = roles[admin]`

It does not work either, as shiro documentation says, that first path filter match wins.
The second one will never match.

Is there another way to configure shiro, to match any filter for a specified path?

Comment: I believe what you are trying to do is implicit roles as described here: http://shiro.apache.org/authorization.html#Authorization-Roles. Can't you use explicit roles and have the user:edit permission added to the admin role?

Comment: I've managed to give the users having the role ``admin`` the permission ``user:edit:*``. Thought there will be another solution.